# 'sed' date formatting issue

Tags: sed, date, csv, text-formatting

I am getting a file from database using shell script.
Data looks like below after running shell script.This is a pipe separated data file.

```
4676004||2017-09-2900:00:00|13222|0|XYZ|TTTTT||1855467|S|14671
```

After generating the file using spool, below is the command that I am running to format the data.

```
sed -i -E 's/[[:blank:]]+(||$)/\1/g' Test.txt.
```

but the problem is **date** data

`2017-09-2900:00:00`, I need this like `2017-09-29 00:00:00`

I need space between date and time. How this can be done?

Comment: can you post the initial few lines before `sed` processing?

Comment: if [ -f $HOME/data/feed/$1.txt ]; then     
var=$header_info    
sed -i "1s/.*/$var/"  $1.txt           
sed -i '$d'  $1.txt            
sed -i 's/ *,/,/g' $1.txt           
sed -i -E 's/[[:blank:]]+(||$)/\1/g' $1.txt
sed -i 's/^[[:blank:]]*$//' $1.txt

Comment: That code belongs in your question where we can see it in context. Not posted as a comment where it can be overlooked. Please edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 3):

Just do.

```
sed 's/....-..-../& /' infile
```

Assuming there is always one pattern can match with `xxxx-xx-xx` format.

Or at first in your SQL you need to tell `substr` in `select` command to do this job to you.

```
select ... '|' || substr(mydate,1,10) || subtsr(mydate,11,8) || '|'  ...
```

Comment: That's a novel solution, using Morse code :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed -E 's/([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}):/\1 \2:/' file
4676004||2017-09-29 00:00:00|13222|0|XYZ|TTTTT||1855467|S|14671
```

This is assuming that the only place in the input line where four digits occur before a `:` is in the date string.  The `sed` substitution separates the two groups of two digits with a space.

Comment: I got the required solution..Thanks for your help..

Comment: @unknown In that case, if you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!" :-)

Comment: And to elaborate a bit on @Kusalananda's comment,  accepting an answer is not only for saying "Thank you": it indicates to *future visitors* that the answer solved the problem. That's what makes SE useful (well, at least *one* of the things that makes SE useful).